# How solve the "Can't start MATLAB engine" command?

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-engine

(1) Firstly, I created a Makefile as follows:

```
MATLABROOT=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b

all: engdemo

engdemo:
    $(MATLABROOT)/bin/mex -f $(MATLABROOT)/bin/engopts.sh $(MATLABROOT)/extern/examples/eng_mat/engdemo.cpp -o engdemo

clean:
    rm -f engdemo *.o
```

(2) I ran it with 'make' command and gives following output:

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/mex -f /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/engopts.sh /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/extern/examples/eng_mat/engdemo.cpp -o engdemo

Warning: You are using gcc version "4.6.1-9ubuntu3)".  The version
         currently supported with MEX is "4.3.4".
         For a list of currently supported compilers see: 
         http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release/

/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/extern/examples/eng_mat/engdemo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/extern/examples/eng_mat/engdemo.cpp:107:32: warning: ignoring return value of ‘char* fgets(char*, int, FILE*)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
```

(3) Then, I ran:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnx86:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/sys/os/glnx86
```

(4) Finally, I ran ./engdemo, where the output was:

```
matlab: Command not found.
```

Can't start MATLAB engine

How can i start MATLAB engine?

Comment: You simply need to ensure that the relevant directory is on your path (i.e. listed in your `$PATH` environment variable).

Comment: Do i need to add another environment variable? Used variable is correct. I am confused!!

Comment: If the problem is PATH environment variable, What is the correct PATH? I have changed to different PATH but the problem is same!!

Comment: try this: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin` before running `./engdemo`

Comment: What should i write instead of PATH? Do i should use PATH name directly or change it to a directory name?

Comment: Thank you. It worked successfully.